# No WinForm Designer Surface in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, desktop-application

I have installed **Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.6.4** with WinForm and Desktop application development support. When I create a new WinForm C# project, it creates a Form1.cs file. But when I double click on the form Form1.cs, it does not show WinForm designer surface where I could drag and drop form controls. Can anyone help what I am missing here.

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On toolbar where form1.cs on far right side there is an arrow.  Click on arrow and select the designer.cs file.

Comment: Try *View Designer* from the `Form1.cs` context menu in solution explorer or `Shift`+`F7`

Comment: @jdweng if I click on arrow, it shows Form1.Designer.cs. When I double click on Form1.Designer.cs, it opens code for partial class Form1 which is Windows Form Designer generated code. Not matter whether I double click Form1.cs or Form1.Designer.cs, it does not show WinForm designer surface rather it opens code window

Comment: @Filburt, if I right click and select View Designer or press Shift + F7, it opens up code window for public partial class Form1 : Form. It does not show Designer surface.

Comment: @Ralf, I have created a brand new C# WinForm project with only one form Form1 that is created by default. If I press F7, it shows code but when I press Shift + F7 is again shows code and does not show the designer surface.

Comment: Try menu : File : Save Program.cs AS  and select a folder where you have read/write access.  The program is not running.

Comment: Verify that the VS WinForms Designer is enabled in Tools->Options -- I don't remember whether in this version of VS you have to enable it explicitly (as it once was also in other versions of VS). It could be in `Environment->Preview Features`

Comment: @Jimi, Under Tools->Options->Windows Form Designer, I do not see a setting to explicitly enable Designer Surface. Do you know where can I find this setting?

Comment: Nope. Not there, see my previous comment -- You haven't specified whether you picket a .NET Framework or .NET Project. If the latter, try again with a .NET Framework Project Template. You might also be missing some workloads / components. Verify in the installer for that. Also, if you haven't, download and install the .NET 7 Development package (from MS)

Comment: @Jimi under ```Environment->Preview Features```, there was only one setting ```Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps``` which is related to .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.0. I have created a C# WinForm project for .NET 6.0. Even enabling this setting does not show designer surface.

Comment: @Jimi, I have selected ```Windows Forms App (C#)``` project template from New Project dialog. Then I selected Next, ```.NET 6.0``` as Framework. I have installed, ```Windows Desktop Development``` workload and components during installation of Visual Studio 2022 community edition. What else I need to install, to view Designer Surface.

Comment: @Jimi, your suggestion worked. Thanks. Under ```Environment->Preview Features```, there is a setting ```Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps```. Select this setting and Designer Surface will show when you double click form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jimi, your suggestion worked. Thanks. Under `Environment->Preview Features`, there is a setting `Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps`. Select this setting and Designer Surface will show when you double click form.

Comment: As a (reiterated, I know) suggestion: download, install and target .NET 7, not .NET 6, in your Project. Even if it's *just a test*

Comment: @Jimi, I am working on an old project that is already developed using ```.NET 6.0```. Hopefully in future projects, I will use ```.NET 7.0```

Comment: It's backward-compatible